# Doctrine 2 - Get total when using limit via repository

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, limit

I'm new to Doctrine, and I just could not find a way to get the **total** number of results when using limit with `Criteria` (via `setMaxResults` function) in the `EntityRepository::matching` method.

In my repository (not an `extend` of EntityRepository), I'm using the following (I know this is not the optimal code, it is used just to learn Doctrine):

```
public function getAll($query = null) {
    if ($query instanceof Criteria) {
        $users = $this->em->getRepository('App\Entities\User')->matching($query)->toArray();
    } else {
        $users = $this->em->getRepository('App\Entities\User')->findAll();
    }
    return $users;
}
```

Now lets say that the Criteria is defined like so:

```
$query = Criteria::create();
$query->where(Criteria::expr()->contains('username', 'ron'));
$query->setMaxResults(10);
```

And there are actually more than 10 users that match that.

How can I get the total number of the users that match the criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set `maxResults` to 10, you get 10 results ;).

Why don't you call `getAll()` to get all results and apply the `MaxResults` later?

```
//search for Ron's
$query = Criteria::create();
$query->where(Criteria::expr()->contains('username', 'ron'));

//check how many Ron's your database can find
$count = $repo->getAll($query)->count();

//get the first 10 records
$query->setMaxResults(10);
$users = $repo->getAll($query);
```

Comment: I've tried to do it in a single query, but I guess COUNT(*) that Doctrine does as the first query (without the limit) is fast enough to not have a big "overhead" impact. Thanks :)